# Javascript not working when Alert is removed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I use D3.js and upon loading data from csv file the page isn't rendering when I remove the alert() statements. I;'m not a js specialist and I know it's something to do with asynchronous modes of operation but I don't know what to change.

when     alert("AAAAAAAA"); is removed it works I appreciate this is a bespoke
issue so the other posts on the subject were not easily understood.

Many Thanks

Andy

```
</style>
<div id='dashboard2' align="center"></div>
<div id='dashboard' align="center"></div>
<script src="/xxxxxxxx/templates/uber/js/d3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var climate_csv = function()
{
    d3.csv("/xxxxxxxx/templates/uber/js/theclimate.csv", function(climate_statistics)
    {
        //prices is an array of json objects containing the data in from the csv
        console.log("climate_statistics:", climate_statistics)
        climate_data = climate_statistics.map(function(d)
        {
            //each d is one line of the csv file represented as a json object
            console.log("d", d)
            month = d.month;
            console.log("month:", d.month, month)
            low = +d.low;
            console.log("low:", d.low, low)
            high = +d.high;
            console.log("high:", d.high, high)
            rainfall = +d.rainfall;
            console.log("rainfall:", d.rainfall, rainfall)
            sunshine = +d.sunshine;
            console.log("sunshine:", d.sunshine, sunshine)
            nighttime = +d.nighttime;
            console.log("nighttime:", d.nighttime, nighttime);
          return {"Month": month, "cStats": {"low": low , "high": high} , "rainfall": rainfall , "sun":{"Sunshine": sunshine , "Nighttime": nighttime}}
       })
    })
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var climateStats2=[
 {TempRange:'Low',cStats:{low:0}}
];

var climateStats3=[
 {TempRange3:'High',cStats:{high:0}}
];

var climateStats4=[
 {TempRange4:'Rainfall',cStats:{rainfall:0}}
];

var climateStats5=[
 {TempRange4:'Rainfall',cStats5:{lower5:0, upper5:0}}
];

        climate_csv();

alert("AAAAAAAA");

        dashboard('#dashboard',climate_data,climateStats2,climateStats3,climateStats4,climateStats5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your data is not fully loaded, when you call dashboard. It works with the `alert` because while the alert is open, your script is paused. Another thing is, that you are using global variables here. Let's avoid this using callbacks.

D3's `csv` function uses a callback and calls it, when the data is ready.

```
d3.csv("/xxxxxxxx/templates/uber/js/theclimate.csv", function(climate_statistics) {
  /* ... */
});
```

You can now either call the dashboard function inside the callback, or add a callback to your function. Let's do the latter here:

```
var climate_csv = function( callback ) {
  d3.csv(
    "/xxxxxxxx/templates/uber/js/theclimate.csv",
    function( climate_statistics ) {

    var climate_data = climate_statistics.map(function( d ) {
      month = d.month;
      low = +d.low;
      high = +d.high;
      rainfall = +d.rainfall;
      sunshine = +d.sunshine;
      nighttime = +d.nighttime;
      return {
        "Month": month,
        "cStats": {
          "low": low,
          "high": high
        },
        "rainfall": rainfall,
        "sun": {
          "Sunshine": sunshine,
          "Nighttime": nighttime
        }
      };
    });

    // we are done with mapping our data
    // let's call the callback with the data
    callback(climate_data);
  });
};

/* ... */

climate_csv(function( climate_data ) {
  dashboard('#dashboard', climate_data, climateStats2, climateStats3,
    climateStats4, climateStats5);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the function that is not working when you remove the alert inside the success callback, that will make the trick.
.csv works async, so when you put the alert, the request is completed on the background, when you remove it no "wait time" is added (as it should be) and that's why it's not working.

Not using d3.js, but this doc could help:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV

```
d3.csv("path/to/file.csv")
    .row(function(d) { return {key: d.key, value: +d.value}; })
    .get(function(error, rows) { console.log(rows); });
```

Hope it helps.